# React native useEffect does not work when it's in same screen or back to screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, function, use-effect, react-navigation-v5

I am using [react naviagtion 5](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/) and typescript for my mobile.

I have two sets of data in the database, one is `date` and one is `time`. Both are expecting strings.

I made one `POST` request when the user chooses the date, and that time will be selected for the user. I made a helper function for when the user's choosing time will be over, in which case I show them an alert on the front-end that shows

> "Your selected time expired!"

After showing that Alert. I forcefully clear the delivery time. My logic works fine. But I am having issue that when I am in the same screen or minimise the app, the `useEffect` does not trigger. If I go different screen and come back to that delivery screen then it triggers. I don't know how to hot reload the app when selecting time expired even though I am in the same screen or minimise the app.

I share my code in [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/@alakdam/useeffect)

**This is my sample code**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Text,View, Alert, Button} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

    const deliveryDate = "2021-06-21";
    const deliveryTime = "10:00-10:03";

    const isTimeWindowExpired = (date: string, time: string) => {
        const [startTime] = time.split('-');
        const newDate = new Date(`${date}T${startTime}`);
    
        if (newDate.getTime() < new Date().getTime()) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      
    };
        
function Home() {
    const navigation = useNavigation()

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
       <Text>Home</Text>
         <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}


function SecondHome() {
      const navigation = useNavigation()

   React.useEffect(() => {
    const isExpired = isTimeWindowExpired(deliveryDate, deliveryTime);
    const expirationTrigger = () => {
      Alert.alert("Time Expired");
   
    };
    if (isExpired) {
      expirationTrigger();
    }
  }, [deliveryDate, deliveryTime]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
       <Text>useEffect does not trigger when it's in same screen or minimisse</Text>
         <Text>Home</Text>
         <Button
        title="Go back Home"
        onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
      />
    </View>
  );
}



const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="home" detachInactiveScreens>
        <Stack.Screen name="home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="details" component={SecondHome} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `useIsFocused` hook from react-navigation could help you.
It basically checks, if the screen is looked at. Adding it into `useEffect` and its dependencies, the `useEffect` will trigger every time `isFocused` changes its value. When you leave the screen (to another screen or minimizing the app) it's `false` and when you come back, it is `true` back again.

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';


function SecondHome() {
    const navigation = useNavigation()
    const isFocused = useIsFocused();

    React.useEffect(() => {
    if(isFocused) {
      const isExpired = isTimeWindowExpired(deliveryDate, deliveryTime);
      const expirationTrigger = () => Alert.alert("Time Expired");
      if (isExpired) {
        expirationTrigger();
      }
    }
  }, [deliveryDate, deliveryTime, isFocused]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
       <Text>useEffect does not trigger when it's in same screen or minimisse</Text>
         <Text>Home</Text>
         <Button
        title="Go back Home"
        onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

You can read more about it here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-is-focused/